# For the question attached, how would you find the values of the vectors BA and BC?

Tags: vectors

I know that first, you would use the rule

vector BA x vector BC= |vector BA| * |vector BC| * cos[x]
and then find the values of vectors BA and BC in terms of a, b and c but I'm not sure as to how...

[image: question i am not sure with]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want to use the rule
$$
    \overrightarrow{BA} \cdot \overrightarrow{BC}
    = \left|\overrightarrow{BA}\right| \left|\overrightarrow{BC}\right| \cos(\angle ABC)
$$
When it says “$A$ is the point defined by the position vector $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{i} + 3\mathbf{j}$,” it means $A$ is the point $(1,3)$.  Similarly, you can find the coordinates of $B$ and $C$, and from those the components of $\overrightarrow{BA}$ and $\overrightarrow{BC}$.

Comment: ok... could you please tell me how to make the components of BA and BC from the co-ordinates? thank you

Comment: That should be covered in your textbook or notes.  The basic idea is that $\overrightarrow{BA}$ is the *displacement* from $B$ to $A$.  If you're standing on $B$, how much in each direction do you need to go to get to $A$?